# Clamping Color Ramp Values

Tags: node-editor, color

This is my first time asking anything on here, but I have been using Blender for many years now. I am currently working on a specific type of toon shader. I want it to be able to automate any image and texture into its definite toon values.

Currently, I am stuck. I have a Color Ramp set up on constant to give a toon effect, but whenever I use Color Ramps it always replaces the values of the original with whatever values are set in the ramp. I know that is what it is supposed to do, but I just want the constant part from the ramp and not the values that come from it. I know I could just change the values of the ramp to work for it, but I don't want to have to change them every time. My final project that this is meant for has many different values and I don't want to have to manually do each one.[image: Without Coor Ramp][image: With the Color Ramp]

Answer (score 2):

If I understandyour question, as you are getting from  the color ramp a shading information, you can use it as a color multiplyer before the actual shader.

[image]

Comment: not exactly. This is so hard to explain over text. I know I can add the colour back in by using multiply or value mix, but I'm trying to get a specific value clamp on my colour ramp. so let's say that we shade a sphere in diffuse lighting, the shadow is around 40% value, and the Light is about 80% Value well once I add this colour ramp to it automatically replaces those with 100% Value for shadows and 0% for highlights. I want to keep the values but use a constant effect.

Comment: @AlanWyatt So you want the value to be run through the ramp but not hue and saturation?  If so, then using a Separate HSV and Combine HSV pair with the hue and saturation passed right through and the value sent through a color ramp should do what you want.

Comment: I think he wanted to "Quantize" the original values, without replacing them with the predefined values of the color ramp; but in some way he has to define the parameters of the quantization.